# special characters in a variable assistance

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, registry

I'm trying to make a reg query a variable. I can get it to work in win10 but when I try XP it doesn't work. Its a reg query to determin .net4 installed.

```
set "net4=REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP" | find /i "4.0" > NUL || ".NetFx40.exe" /passive /norestart"
```

to test on win 10, if I change 4.0 to 5.0 the installer starts, leave on 4 it skips as expected.

On XP as soon as it hits the setting variable element it just tries to install 
regardless that it's already installed. I'm guessing the pipes and things are breaking the entry, how can I resolve this, thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it is the source of the problem you're describing but your quotation marks (`"`) may cause some issues. Remember that **one `"` will be closed by the first following `"`**. I would advise you to just remove the first `"` and the very last `"` and then escape each `|` with a `^`. So you could start by replacing your code by `set net4=REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP" ^| find /i "4.0" > NUL ^|^| ".NetFx40.exe" /passive /norestart`

Comment: the `>` must also be escaped with `^`! my apologies, I forgot to mention it in my previous comment

Comment: Yes! thanks works perfect, I did have a go at escaping like that but the busy quotations, as you spotted, were causing an issue. wonder why win 10 doesnt needs escapes though. here is a working code snippet **set net4=REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP" ^| find /i "5.0" ^> NUL ^|^| "NetFx40.exe" /passive /norestart**

Comment: Win 10 didn't need the escapes probably because the quotes just were on the right place by chance. Everything between the opening and closing quotes is escaped and considered as is (except the `%` for variables and the `!` when delayed expansion is used). But as I am not that experienced in Windows XP I don't know exactly where the different behavior came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working line as suggested by [J.Baoby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7170434/j-baoby):

```
set net4=REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP" ^| find /i "4.0" ^> NUL ^|^| ".NetFx40.exe" /passive /norestart
```